Conflict org.modelmapper.ModelMapper and jakarta.persistence.Version // Java (Spring Data)
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @Version
    private Long version;
}

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cats")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Cat extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private User owner;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double weight;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CatRequest {

    private String name;

    private Long ownerId;

    private Double weight;
}

@Override
    @Transactional
    public CatResponse createCat(CatRequest request) {
        Cat cat = mapper.map(request, Cat.class);

        cat = catRepository.save(cat);

        return mapper.map(cat, CatResponse.class);
    }

I have a BaseEntity class that has a version field. And the Cat class that inherits from BaseEntity. If i use ModelMapper to convert the CatRequest class to Cat and try to save it to the database, the exception 'org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Detached entity with generated id '3' has an uninitialized version value 'null' : com.example.cats_service.model.entity.Cat.version' will be thrown.
However, if i convert manually using setters, the version sets correctly and the exception is not thrown.
